# Protect contents of Electron app from being stolen

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm planning to create an Electron app. The app has content of multiple mp3/png/svg files which are going to be rendered inside the app. I don't want anyone to open an audio or an image outside of the app. I researched a lot to find a solution to protect theses file so that if someone installed the app won't be able to open and use the files outside of my app but it seems that it's not possible...

Note: simple protection solution with minimal security is accepted too...

Note 2: Can we store the files (mp3/ png/svg) without any extension (this way users can not open them directly on their machine) and then open the files via electron app (we have the name and extension stored in our app so we have the extension to attach to preloaded file and open the file) I mean can we preload the audio file without extension and then open the preloaded audio with mp3 format as a work around?

Comment: Simply removing the file extension won't stop good software from playing back/displaying the given file types. Even more so, since on Linux the file type is determined by the file's magic bytes if it has no extension and there's even an utility, `fie` which will tell any user the exact file format. Thus, encryption could be a feasible approach -- have you looked into that?

Comment: You might investigate the [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encrypted_Media_Extensions_API#specifications) browser API if your media assets are high enough in value. Or, you could watermark them. Notice that it's almost impossible to stop somebody from making screen grabs. So if your user can see the media, she can copy it.

Answer (score 3):

I saw a clever "solution" for protecting multimedia assets back in the days of interactive CD-ROMS.

The trick was to write some junk text to the end of the .mp3 or video file in order to corrupt the file and make it unplayable. Then in the app, to play the file, the file would be written to a temporary directory with the junk text removed so it could be played.

Not foolproof by any means but it prevents casual copying assets out of the app bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'm looking for something like this... but how can I do it with Electron.. is it capable of editing a file ?

Comment: Yes  it can using the [Node `fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). And fwiw – I don't think editing the contents of the app bundle is generally considered a "good idea" (but I may be wrong) – so copying the file to your app's application support directory would probably be better.